# Add Windows while keeping Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I use Ubuntu 14.04.1; and I want to install Vista to dual-boot. Made a 100 GB partition for Vista and formatted it to NTFS with Gparted. But Vista refuses to install because there is "no space"

I would not like to uninstall Ubuntu.

Can the strange "no space" problem be overcome from the terminal's command line? Force installation of software on specific partition?

Comment: Not quite familiar with installing Windows, but from what I heard , Windows really needs to be installed by itself first, then other OSs. Perhaps, you're going to be better off with a virtual machine

Comment: I don't know much about vista, just format your 100GB drive after booting from CD or USB and then try to install it. Format option is available in windows 7 and newer options. Just check.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar issue where Windows (7) refused to install to an MBR partitioned disk, while another GPT partitioned disk was still attached.

A list of things to try out or look for:

- Remove all disks with unsupported partition table types or convert or backup and restore to a supported partition table type.
- Boot the installation media the correct way for the desired installation mode or use up to date installation media that support newer UEFI type machines.

Changing the partition table or boot mode requires to reinstall or reconfigure existing bootloaders.

A similar question has been asked on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/q/333293/252532). This is an issue with Windows, not Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution, the question should have been asked where Windows is on-topic.